# Finder tag not working for all folders

Tags: finder-tag

I set the `red` tag for the folder `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData` but if I search all files or folders with the `red` tag, this doesn't show up.

Comment: Under System Preferences > Spotlight > Search Results tab, is Developer checked?

Comment: @tubedogg, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Probably need to search 'System files - are included'.
Regular search may not look in there.

[image]

Comment: Still doesn't work. I have `xtraFinder` installed, could it be the problem? I even tried [this](https://github.com/jdberry/tag) but it still not showing up.

Comment: I don't have Xcode any more, but still have Command Line Tools folder in that location. Works for me with that as a search term - updating my picture to reflect that [& confirmed it won't find it without 'system files']

Comment: It still doesn't work for me.